# Swift - Filter an array by pruning child "owned" items from a given parent

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have a relationship which can be described as:

`Factory -< Engine`

A player only has a reference to `engines` that he owns;

ie:

`Player: { name: "Bob", engines: [Engine]() }`

I wish to filter the factories on whether a certain player can afford the factory; but also I want to filter out all the engines that the player already owns.

That is to say,

> a player can only ever buy each factory once.

..

My code to filter out affordable factories is this:

```
  let results = factories.filter { (factory:Factory) -> Bool in
      return ((factory.cost <= Int(firstPlayer.cash)) && (factory.isUnlocked))
  }
```

My code to filter engines that a player owns, for a given parent factory

```
  let ownedEngines = player.engines.filter { (eng:Engine) -> Bool in
      return ((eng.owner == player) && (eng.parent == factory))
  }
```

But how to I combine them to say;

Give me a list of all factories that I don't already own, and that I can afford?

Many thanks

---

Edit: Classes outlines follow

```
class Factory {
  var name: String
  var cost: Int
  var engines: [Engine] = [Engine]()
}

class Engine {
  var name: String 
  weak var parent: Factory?
  weak var owner: Player?
  var units: Int
}

class Player {
  var name: String
  var cash: Int
  var engines: [Engine] = [Engine]()
}
```

Further info

The best way I can describe it is;

The game represents several Factories collected together in [decks].
Each `deck` has multiple cards in it; these are the Engines.
Each player cannot buy the same factory more than once.

I need a reference to how many `units` and other meta data for the child object, hence this is why there is an `Engine` entity.

So when a player buys a factory, they in fact buy an Engine and never directly own the Factory.  All references can be gathered from the child objects.

I require to filter out:

- my `decks` of all factories that I can afford
- all factories that I already own via my engine cards

So I do it this way currently;

```
// static Function in my factory model
    public static func filterDecksForCash(decks: [Factory], cash:Int) -> [Factory] {
            let results = decks.filter { (f:Factory) -> Bool in
                return ((loco.cost <= Int(cash)) && (loco.isUnlocked))
            }
            return results
        }


let decks = Factory.createAll()


        // filter deck for cost, unlock but also all trains but also remove trains they've already purchased
        var results = Factory.filterDecksForCash(decks: decks, cash: firstPlayer.cash)

        for (index, factory) in results.enumerated() {
            for eng in factory.engines {
                if (eng.owner == firstPlayer) {
                    results.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: add your classes implementations please.

Comment: Why are the classes importatnt?  All I'm doing is filtering arrays. I'll add the basic ones stripped out of unimportant info anyway.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're asking for a list of all the *engines* that you don't already own as well as all the *factories* that you can afford. Or do you automatically own the factories that are the parents of the engines that you own?

Comment: To clarify, I am asking for a list of all parents that I do not already own via the child object Engine.  I want to filter out all factories that I can afford too.   If you buy 1 factory, you have 1 engine.  A player never really owns a factory, but an engine; this is because the engines have `Units` and needs an entity to track what units are remaining.

Comment: I decided to simply do a for-loop after my filter to remove the child objects where appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to run a for-loop which prunes off items I don't want.

Issue closed.

I am using also experimenting with a similar function to this;

```
let filtered = decks.filter { (deck:EYLocomotive) -> Bool in
            return ((deck.isUnlocked) && (deck.orders.count > 0))
            }.map({ $0.engines.filter({ (eng:EYEngine) -> Bool in
                return (eng.owner != nil)
            })})
```